# How can I return data from a promise and then pass it through a prop in a react component

Tags: reactjs, expo, es6-promise

I'm in a big struggle.
I try to pass data in useState from sendID because I need it to pass in to the props of my component Exposition but its undefind.

I can not return it because it returns a promise.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DataService from "../services/Services";
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import Expositions from "./Expositions";


const Authenticate = () => {

  const[code, setCode] = useState();

  SecureStore.getItemAsync("device_id").then((response) => {
    console.log("stored id : " + response);
    sendId({"id" : response});
    }
  );
  
    function sendId(deviceId){
      console.log("object id send to api : " + JSON.stringify(deviceId));
      DataService.getInfo(JSON.stringify(deviceId))
        .then((response) => {
          SecureStore.setItemAsync("device_id", response.id);
          console.log("id from api : " + response.id);
          console.log(response.response);
          console.log("here");
          setCode({"id" : 3}); //does'nt work
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }

    //SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("device_id").then((reject) => {
    //});

    console.log("Data :" + JSON.stringify(code)); //undefined
    return (
      <Expositions infections={code}/> //undefined
    );
  
  };
  export default Authenticate;
```

Comment: `sendId ` and `getId` aren't components nor are they custom hooks, they can't use `useState` hook. Fix that then define some valid initial state and place utility functions in an `useEffect` hook with proper dependency so they aren't invoked every render cycle. You `async` functions don't `await` anything so they don't need to be declared `async`. Conditionally render `Expositions` or ensure `Expositions` can handle updated props.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your *async* functions use *await* statement and do not use `.then` for promises like `SecureStore.getItemAsync` and `DataService.getInfo`. If you don't use *await*, those functions will return the value before the promise execution finish.